# how to get defun to accept a list as its argument

Tags: lisp

I am trying to learn lisp and searched the question and found a response I couldnt understand. Could someone help me with what I am trying.

SO I have created a basic function RotateL which should take a list as its argument and returns a new list in which the former first element becomes last.

So I created

```
    (defun rotate (L)
                   (Append ( rest L) (first L)))
ROTATE
```

I can't set L as a (a b c) I tried `SETQ L '( a b c)` and when at the end I did `(rotate L)` it gives me an error as well.

I think its the fact that I am trying to put a list rather then an element in value L.

Could someone explain and help please.

Comment: downvoted because of bad spelling, bad formatting, missing interaction example and missing error message.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are deeply lost:

```
? (defun rotate (L) (append (rest L) (first L)))
ROTATE

? (rotate '(a b c))
(B C . A)

? (setq X '(x y z))
(X Y Z)
? (rotate X)
(Y Z . X)
```

But you see that your function is broken, correcting by adding a `list`:

```
? (defun rotate (L) (append (rest L) (list (first L))))
ROTATE
? (rotate '(a b c))
(B C A)
? (rotate X)
(Y Z X)
```

You may want to look up the meaning of *formal* and *actual* parameters.